# Inno Setup: changing from 32bit to 64bit - how to move/delete/unregister old files?

Tags: inno-setup, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying help out a developer who's program for 64bit window was incorrectly installing itself as 32bit into C:\Program Files (x86)\ directory and a .dll file was registered with regserver flag.

The new script installs it correctly, however what would be the best approach to handle previously installed version to remove old files and unregister the .dll?
If possible with checking the previous version number and without running the uninstaller, due to possibility of lost user settings.

Thank you.

P.S.
Here is an example of what we have right now:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Test
AppVerName=Test 3.5.0 (64bits)
AppVersion=3.5.0
AppPublisher=Me
DefaultDirName={pf}\TestDir
DefaultGroupName=Test
OutputBaseFilename=Test64
Compression=lzma2
ChangesAssociations=yes
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64

[Files]
Source: "{app}\TestExt64.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: regserver restartreplace uninsrestartdelete ignoreversion
```

Comment: I know you want to avoid that, but I would just save those user settings and run uninstaller. Uninstallation is the cleanest way you can go in this case. Anything else will be just "hacking".

Comment: How Inno will handle locked files during uninstall? I mean, the previous installation didn't have restartreplace flag on files, and it would give error message during upgrades.
So, will running uninstall command from this version properly uninstall and use runonce method to complete uninstall in case locked files and continue installation automatically after reboot?

Comment: The uninstaller should not be removing user settings in the first place (it's not even possible to do so if multiple users have been running the app). As for locked files, you need to ensure that your app is not running before you run the uninstall/install. But if they're still locked, the uninstall will not remove them unless you used the `uninsrestartdelete` flag at the time of install. If you did use this flag, then you will need to use `PrepareToInstall` to run the uninstaller.

Comment: Yes, we do use uninsrestartdelete flag, but only in new installation script. Before nothing like this was used.
Would you be so kind and give an example how to exactly run the uninstaller in this case?
Thank you.